# php zip file to multiple zip files

Tags: php, zip

I am using php to generate a file that can become up to 50MB. At the end of the script I need to send the file to a given email address. I want to cut up the file into multiple chunks so I can send emails with not too big attachments each.
The obvious solution seems to me to zip the file into zip parts. But I can't seem to find how to split a file using zip in php.

Can anyone help me out, or maybe point me to a better solution? :)

Comment: Check out this fine class: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1900-PHP-Zip-split-large-file-into-smaller-parts-.html

Comment: E-mail is not meant for this. Can't you use FTP? Dropbox? Anyhting else?

Answer (score 0):

easyzip has a bug for current versions of php. replace this lines:

```
define(FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND,'Error: gzcompress() function is not found');
define(FILE_NOT_FOUND,'Error: file is not found');
define(DIRECTORY_NOT_FOUND,'Error: directory is not found');
```

with below:

```
define("FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND",'Error: gzcompress() function is not found');
define("FILE_NOT_FOUND",'Error: file is not found');
define("DIRECTORY_NOT_FOUND",'Error: directory is not found');
```